# How to create a number of directories with consecutive names in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm coding a script that runs an executable, and everytime the executable runs properly, it has to create a directory and an output file, and then move the file inside the directory. The problem comes with the names of the directories. I pass the name as an argument to the script, but the names aren't the ones I want to be, here's the code:

```
IF ($args.Count -eq 2 -or $args.Count -eq 3) {
    $c = 0
    $i = 0
    $cont = 1
    do {
        ./simula.exe $cont RES
        IF ($? -ne 0) {
            $c = $c +1;
            New-Item $args$c -ItemType directory
            Move-Item RES $args$c
        }
        ELSE {
            $i = $i +1;
        }
        $cont = $cont +1;
}
while ($c -le $args[1])
    $c = $c -1;
    "Shan generat $c simulacions correctes."
    "Hi ha hagut $i simulacions erronies."
}   
ELSE {
    "Nombre de parametres incorrecte"
}
```

If I run it like this: `.\treball DIREC 10` it should create 11 folders with the name DIREC1, DIREC2, ... DIREC11 and place 1 file named RES inside each directory. However the names of the directories it creates are: DIREC101, DIREC102, ... DIREC1011.
I've been touching some things in the New-Item line but I can't get to the names I need. How can I do it?

Comment: Something like this:
`$folder_name = $args[0] + $c;
New-Item $folder_name -ItemType directory;
Move-Item RES $folder_name` - should work like you expect. But things like args[0] are ugly. If it's not a temporary or test script you should use param() and give your arguments names.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then the part `$args$c` in below command from your script, just doing a string concatanation cause per documentation that's the `filename` in `new-item` commandlet.

```
New-Item $args$c -ItemType directory
```

So to check if you do like below, it will generate a directory named `101`

```
$argc = 10
$c = 1
New-Item $argc$c -ItemType directory
```

(OR) like below then a directory named `10+1`

```
$argc = 10
$c = 1
New-Item $argc + $c -ItemType directory
```

so, to achieve your goal you need to do the addition before hand and then pass it as argument to the `new-item` commandlet like below and now it will create a directory named `11`

```
$argc = 10
$c = 1
$var = [int]$argc+[int]$c
New-Item $var -ItemType directory
```